# How to get top and bottom number of a number in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, numbers, decimal

I have a number like 73
how get max and min like 70 and 80.
or 173 I want to get 170 and 180 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ceil(73/10) * 10 // round up 80
round(73/10) * 10 // round down 70
```

Playground:
[image]

EDIT: Here just provide an idea.

```
let value: Int = 75

func min(_ value: Int) {
    value - value % 10
}

func max(_ value: Int) {
    value + 10 - value % 10
}

min(value)

max(value)
```

Comment: Sorry both of these code return 80.

Comment: @reza_khalafi are you sure? Check the edited image.

Comment: Please check 75 or 76 .

Comment: See my edit, might not proper, shouldn't be a hard thing.